# Move entire XML code inside another XML tag

Tags: xslt

I have XML code and I want to put two XML tags in the beginning of the XML code so all the code will come under those two tags.

Any ideas how to achieve that with XSLT? I am a newbie to XSLT and tried the whole day in vain... Any help would really be appreciated.

I have an XML which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:PCN xmlns:ns0="abc">
    <PCD>
        <PC>
            <TID>123456</TID>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            <Type>M</Type>
        </PC>
        <PC>
            <TID>123457</TID>
            <Sequence>2</Sequence>
            <Type>M</Type>
        </PC>
    </PCD>
</ns0:PCN>
```

and I need to transform it to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="xyz">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <ns0:PCN xmlns:ns0="abc">
            <PCD>
                <PC>
                    <TID>123456</TID>
                    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
                    <Type>M</Type>
                </PC>
                <PC>
                    <TID>123457</TID>
                    <Sequence>2</Sequence>
                    <Type>M</Type>
                </PC>
            </PCD>
        </ns0:PCN>
    </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Please find below my attempted code. This is my first try and I have written this after referring to several codes of XSLT. It is not giving me desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ns0:PCN">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="xyz"/>
    <ns0:Message1/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the wanted result? With the `ns0` prefix redefined? In any case, this is not difficult - where exactly are you stuck with this?  Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Hi Michael ,I have updated my question with attempted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="xyz">
        <ns0:Message1>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </ns0:Message1>
    </ns0:Messages>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZK